# How to compress multiple files with iOS Compression Framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, compression, zlib

How can I compress multiple files into one `.zlib` compressed file using only the native [Compression Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression)?

I would like to achieve what can be done using external libraries for `.zip` files, in which you give them a directory and they create a `.zip` archive with all the files in the directory.

Comment: https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip - do you try something like this?

Comment: @Nikdemm I would like to try and use the native library instead of an external library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ZIP Foundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation) uses the native Compression framework.
If you don't need the ZIP functionality, you can have a look at the [`Data+Compression.swift`](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation/blob/development/Sources/ZIPFoundation/Data%2BCompression.swift#L116) extension. It contains the compression and decompression methods that implement stream based, zlib compatible encoding/decoding.